# Chrome.serial.onReceive event divides bytes in responce from device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, serial-port, google-chrome-app

I'm building an app for Google Chrome that gets some bytes from device via COM (usb) port.

The code:

```
// connects the device
function connect(port_name, timeout) {
    chrome.serial.connect(port_name, {
        bitrate: 115200,
        bufferSize: 32768,
        dataBits: "eight",
        stopBits: "one",
        parityBit: "no",
        sendTimeout: timeout,
        receiveTimeout: timeout
    }, function(connectionInfo) {
        if (typeof (connectionInfo) !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof (connectionInfo.connectionId) !== 'undefined' && connectionInfo.connectionId < 1) {
                console.log('Connection error #1');
            } else {
                sessionStorage.setItem('connection', connectionInfo.connectionId);
            }
        }
    })
}
// sends bytes to device
function send_bytes(bytes) {
    var bytes_to_send = new Uint8Array(bytes);
    var connection = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('connection'));
    chrome.serial.send(connection, (bytes_to_send).buffer, function(sent_data) {});
}
// recieves the data
chrome.serial.onReceive.addListener(function(data_recieved) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(data_recieved.data);
    var final_hex = [];
    for (byte in arr) {
        final_hex.push(arr[byte].toString(16));
    }
    console.log('====== HEX ======');
    console.log(final_hex);
});
```

If I run next code in console several times:

```
connect('COM5',15000); // we connected!
send_bytes([0x05, 0xAD, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB6]); // bytes away! ( runs N times)
```

Usually I receive correct HEX sequence:

```
["6", "2", "16", "ad", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "10", "a", "6", "10", "20", "58", "2", "0", "0", "b5", "c0", "ea", "6a", "0", "c", "34"]
```

But sometimes I receive bytes separately, in two .onReceive callbacks:

```
 ["6", "2", "16", "ad", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "10", "a", "6", "10", "20"]
 ["58", "2", "0", "0", "b5", "c0", "ea", "6a", "0", "c", "34"]
```

At first look, this happens because Chrome thinks that device completed sending data, and next part of data comes like new answer from device.
I did not find any options for "time to wait for the next byte while receiving responce from device" in API documentation.

How to prevent byte sequence from separating by chrome.serial.onReceive?

Comment: You are _not_ building an extension. It's an App, since `chrome.serial` is only applicable to apps.

Comment: Maybe it happens when the buffer is almost full. If the response length is always constant, try setting the buffer size to a multiple e.g. 26 * 1000. But  why can't you use chunked responses properly?

Comment: One can also try flushing after reading the data.

Comment: @wOxxOm
I tried set up a 32 * 1024 buffer, no effect.

Comment: @wOxxOm
 I need all bytes from responce to read the exact byte in sequence, for example i need data from 14th byte: parseInt(recievedBytes[14],16).toString(2)[5] = 0;
If i`ll do it only with one part of bytes, value that i get from [14] could be wrong or just 'undefined' if recievedBytes.length < 14 ;
@Xan also tried to flush connection after .onReceive event - same story with chunked bytes

Comment: @wOxxOm , 32 bytes for heavier requests, bufferSize: 1024*26, does not  make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postpone processing if the incoming array is less than minimum response length, save the chunk and process it in the next event.

```
var MIN_RESPONSE_LENGTH = 26;
var incoming = new Uint8Array();

chrome.serial.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
    appendBuffer(info.data);
    if (incoming.length < MIN_RESPONSE_LENGTH) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Timeout waiting for the data, got only:', incoming);
        }, 1000);
        return;
    }
    // process
    console.log(incoming);
    ................
    // reset
    incoming = new Uint8Array();
});

function appendBuffer(arraybuffer) {
    var tmp = new Uint8Array(incoming.length + arraybuffer.byteLength);
    tmp.set(incoming, 0);
    tmp.set(new Uint8Array(arraybuffer), incoming.length);
    incoming = tmp;
}
```

Comment: your code solves the problem, but i still think that proper solution must be through argument for callback function provided by chrome app api. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.